# How can i implement event detection?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want to implement a function that does not abort my program but wait until I press the button on channel 11. And start the program again.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN) #GPIO17

while GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.LOW:
  GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.LOW
  os.system("python /home/pi/gpio.py")
  if not (GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):
      break
```

![enter image description here]
     (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOzdW.jpg)

Comment: I Uploaded a picture to realise what i want to do

Comment: your quesion would get more attention here... https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I very like to use `gpiozero` library for its event handling. I post example with this library below:

```
from gpiozero import Button
from signal import pause
import os

buttonPin = 4

def ButtonPressedCallback():
    #do what you need when button is pressed
    os.system("python /home/pi/gpio.py")

button = Button(buttonPin)
button.when_pressed = ButtonPressedCallback



pause()
```

Or with `RPi.GPIO` library:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN) #GPIO17

def my_callback():
    #do something
    print("button pressed")

GPIO.add_event_detect(11, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=200)
#You can use GPIO.RISING, GPIO.FALLING, GPIO.BOTH

while True:
   time.sleep(0.01)
#Or you can use pause() from signal package
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python.py", line 11, in <module>
    button.when_pressed = ButtonPressedCallback
NameError: name 'ButtonPressedCallback' is not defined

This is the error which he shows me up on the first program which you has send to me

Comment: Sorry, I corrected code. Callback function must be defined before it is assigned to event

Comment: It doesn´t do anythin if i hit my button .. my putton is connected to pin 11 and 17. Which number contains buttonPin= ?

Comment: OK. Connect one wire of button to pin 11 and other wire to GROUND. `buttonPin=11` You had bad wiring. Now it must works

Comment: Okey i  have the solution now

Comment: Can you tell me where was problem?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to use interrupts. Click for details [here](https://medium.com/@rxseger/interrupt-driven-i-o-on-raspberry-pi-3-with-leds-and-pushbuttons-rising-falling-edge-detection-36c14e640fef).

In short an interrupt is something that, well, interrupts normal program flow and passes control an interrupt procedure. When writing programs with GUI you have all sort of `onButtonClick()` methods that do exactly this: they handle interrupts passed by operating system. Int the example in the link this line:

```
GPIO.add_event_detect(BTN_G, GPIO.BOTH, handle)
```

add event detection and passes flow control to `handle()` function.